# Table Column NO for Local Variable in MVC View Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Possible for my question?

My Application in Product Table.

```
No Name
1   Apple
2   Orange
3   PipleApple etc....
```

This above table of No is Sorted By Product ID.But my user is wanted some time prodect table in above product item deleted.Then ID is not ascending.Therefore Number ascending for want local variable in MVC Table of Index.chtml.Possible ....?

```
@model IEnumerable<RenewableEnergyProjcet.Models.REHPDataModels.ProductTable>
<table >
    <thead>        
            <th>
                @Html.Label("No")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Name")
            </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>

                //this part for dynamic local variable assign
            </td>
             <td >
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sort it in the action based on a user supplied value or use a client side table framework that allows you to sort in the browser window. Either way, this is too broad.

Comment: Id number with not possible but user input product of id is possible.I understand but our user is sperate location input therefore item number is correct.please advice.Thank

Comment: I'm sorry, but your English (while far better than my grasp of your language) is very confusing and I really don't know what you are asking.